# Is there a way to return HTML div from one React components to another?

Tags: reactjs, function, promise, return-value

I'm using a function to fetch data from a supabase DB and another function to display that data on the screen. I've tried several ways to do it, but the structure in the picture above is the one that took me further. I'm having problems with displaying the data on the screen.

Context: I already have a function that creates a supabase client and it works perfectly. Also, the function to fetch data works. What I need is to display the info.

Function that fetches data from DB:

```
async function fetchData() {

  //Get's the user ID so the fetch can be made.
  let {data:{user}} = await supabase.auth.getUser();
  let userId = user.identities[0].id

  //fetching the data using user ID
  let { data: properties, error } = await supabase.from('properties').select('id, title, address,num_rooms,num_beds,num_bathrooms,price_per_night,guest_limit').eq('user_id', userId);
  console.log(properties, "this is from fetchData()")
  return properties;
}
```

I use console.log() just to check what kind of object is being generated by the code, it is not important for the function in any way.

**return properties** returns a promise, so I decided to "unpromise" the results, by using:

```
async function unPromiseArray(properties) {
  const arr = await properties;
  console.log(arr, "this is from unPromiseArray()")
  for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i], "this is from the for loop");
    displayData(arr[i]);
  }

}

function displayData(arr) {
  console.log(arr.id)
  console.log(arr.title)
  return <li key={arr.id}>{arr.title}</li>
}
```

This way, I can work the array outside the promise. Hopefully that makes sense to someone here on the Internet ahahaha

Somethings that I concluded:

- It's useless to "unpromise" properties if I can return everything in the fetchData() function - but how do I do that?
- Perhaps there is a very smart way to do this! ahahah I'm still learning!

thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to loop through the data and display them as a list.
Als you can directly pass the properties(which you returns from fetchData) to displayData function.

```
function displayData(properties) {
  console.log(arr.id)
  console.log(arr.title)
  return <li key={arr.id}>{arr.title}</li>
  return (
    <ul>
      {properties.map(property => (
        <li key={property.id}>
          <h2>{property.title}</h2>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```

}